# "refresh token has expired" with VSCode Azure Account Extension in Node

Tags: node.js, azure, visual-studio-code

I'm trying to authenticate in VSCode using the `Azure Account` extension as described here:
https://github.com/Azure/azure-sdk-for-js/blob/master/sdk/identity/identity/README.md#authenticating-via-visual-studio-code

And then by using the `DefaultAzureCredential` as described here:
https://github.com/Azure/azure-sdk-for-js/blob/master/sdk/identity/identity/README.md#authenticating-with-the-defaultazurecredential

I've installed `"@azure/identity": "^1.1.0"` and I'm using the example above to try to authenticate with Azure to get access to an App Configuration instance, but the authentication fails with the error below.

```
invalid_grant(status code 400).
More details:
AADSTS700082: The refresh token has expired due to inactivity. The token was issued on 2020-03-19T16:25:46.3627136Z and was inactive for 90.00:00:00.
Trace ID: 391fe4c9-beb4-4253-9b9f-cada7a647900
Correlation ID: b5b7743b-371e-482a-adb7-8d2260d6029b
Timestamp: 2020-11-03 08:24:13Z
AuthenticationError: invalid_grant(status code 400).
More details:
AADSTS700082: The refresh token has expired due to inactivity. The token was issued on 2020-03-19T16:25:46.3627136Z and was inactive for 90.00:00:00.
Trace ID: 391fe4c9-beb4-4253-9b9f-cada7a647900
Correlation ID: b5b7743b-371e-482a-adb7-8d2260d6029b
Timestamp: 2020-11-03 08:24:13Z
    at IdentityClient.<anonymous> (C:\projects\udi-form\node_modules\@azure\identity\src\client\identityClient.ts:99:21)
    at Generator.next (<anonymous>)
    at fulfilled (C:\projects\udi-form\node_modules\@azure\identity\node_modules\tslib\tslib.js:111:62)
    at processTicksAndRejections (internal/process/task_queues.js:97:5)
```

I've tried signing out and back in multiple times and that seems to be working fine. The status bar in VSCode shows my account and I can pick from my subscriptions so there is a connection present.

I've been debugging for a bit and it does not seem that any of the expected environment variables are set once my script runs. Do I need some additional launch configuration to set this up?

I'm currently using this configuration to run my ts-node script:

```json
        {
            "name": "TS file",
            "type": "node",
            "request": "launch",
            "args": ["${fileBasename}"],
            "runtimeArgs": [
                "-r",
                "ts-node/register",
                "-r",
                "tsconfig-paths/register"
            ],
            "cwd": "${fileDirname}",
            "outputCapture": "std",
            "resolveSourceMapLocations": [
                "${workspaceFolder}/**",
                "!**/node_modules/**"
            ],
            "env": {
                "NODE_ENV": "development"
            }
        },
```

The code I'm testing with is this file. It has no other dependencies apart form the imported `@azure` modules:

```js
import { AppConfigurationClient } from "@azure/app-configuration"
import { DefaultAzureCredential } from "@azure/identity"

import { setLogLevel } from "@azure/logger"
setLogLevel("verbose")

const start = async () => {
    const credentials = new DefaultAzureCredential()
    const appConfigClient = new AppConfigurationClient("[app configuration endpoint]", credentials)
    console.log(await appConfigClient.getConfigurationSetting({ key: "inf/cdnUrl" }))
}

start().catch((error) => {
    console.error(error)
    process.exit(1)
})
```

Edit: Swapping out `DefaultAzureCredential` for `VisualStudioCodeCredential` has no effect.

Comment: Have you tried to use `VisualStudioCodeCredential()` instead of `DefaultAzureCredential()`? I tried with it several months ago, but it returned *Failed to get Azure user details from Visual Studio Code* even though I run the Azure: Sign In command. If you face the same error, I recommend you to use **azure cli**. It also needs the user to log in once.

Comment: Thanks for the suggestion! I tried to call it specifically as well, but it gives me the same error. `DefaultAzureCredential` is supposed to fall back to it, but it's good to check.
I've been using powershell without any issues, but I'll try signing in to azure cli as well.

Comment: Signing in to the azure cli seems to have done something. I've signed in with my management account which has admin access to my subscription, but now I'm getting a 403 RestError. Still, progress is progress. I'll keep looking. Thanks @PamelaPeng !

Comment: About 403 RestError, you could add Add role assignment
 `Storage Blob Data Contributor` to grant read/write/delete permissions to Blob storage resources.

Comment: I already have the Owner role on the storage account as part of my co-administrator role assignment on the subscription. Wouldn't that be sufficient?

Comment: I tried with my account which has the Owner role, and it worked, see [here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/JGKkw.png). Please share more code and details of your error.

Comment: It seems you are using python. I'm currently with node as the title says so there may be a difference there. I've added a code sample.

Answer (score 1):

For others looking at this question. It turns out this was an edge case with my setup.

In short the extension did not properly renegotiate for a new refresh token once the previous one had expired.

It was addressed by the MS team on Github here: https://github.com/microsoft/vscode-azure-account/issues/234